# IMAP client impementation on State Machine boost-ext/sml

Tags: c++, email, state-machine, sml

I made IMAP(IMAPS) notifier on [boost-ext/sml](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml) state machine.
There is an opinion that networking is best done on machines.
Compile in C++20. Tested on GMail server. Uses [karastojko/mailio](https://github.com/karastojko/mailio) (and therefore boost+openssl)

Just checking new emails every `c_RecheckInterval_minutes` minutes.

Here are two key points that concern me:

1. State machine definition in *Impl.h* inside `struct ImapsSm`;
2. State machine using in *Thread.h* inside `void Thread::run()`.

**Impl.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace StateMachine {
// for action
typedef std::function< void(const std:string&) > setActiveTip_t;

// events
struct CheckAccess{};
struct Unavailable{};
struct StartLoop{};
struct HasBreak{};
struct RenewEmail{};
struct ContinueLoop{};

// dependencies
struct dependencyImaps {
    const Credentials m_credentials;
    std::chrono::seconds c_connectTimeout_sec;
};
struct dependencyEmailCount {
    setActiveTip_t fnSetActiveTip;
    unsigned long m_currentEmailCount, m_lastEmailCount;
    std::string lastFrom, lastSubject
};
struct dependencyBreakableSleep {
    const std::chrono::seconds c_RecheckInterval_sec;
    std::condition_variable *m_pConditionVariable;
    std::mutex *m_pcvMutex;
    bool m_bBreak;
};
struct dependencyAvailable {
    bool m_bAvailable;
};

namespace Action {
struct Imap { void operator()(dependencyImaps &imaps, dependencyEmailCount& counter) {
    std::unique_ptr< mailio::imaps > pmailio;
    pmailio = std::make_unique< mailio::imaps >( 
            imaps.m_credentials.host
            , imaps.m_credentials.port
            , imaps.c_connectTimeout_sec
        );
    pmailio ->authenticate(
            imaps.m_credentials.login
            , imaps.m_credentials.password
            , mailio::imaps::auth_method_t::LOGIN
        );
    const char mailbox[] = "inbox";
    pmailio ->select( mailbox );
    std::list< mailio::imap::search_condition_t > search_condition;
    // UNSEEN exclude ALL
    search_condition.emplace_back( mailio::imap::search_condition_t::UNSEEN );
    std::list<unsigned long> results;
    pmailio ->search( search_condition, results );
    unsigned long lastSequenceNumber = results.back( );

    // Find out sender and subject
    mailio::message lastMessage;
    bool header_only;
    pmailio ->fetch( mailbox, lastSequenceNumber, lastMessage, header_only = true );
    counter.m_currentEmailCount = lastSequenceNumber;
    counter.lastFrom = lastMessage.from_to_string( );
    counter.lastSubject = lastMessage.subject( );
} } Imap;

struct BreakableSleep { void operator()(dependencyBreakableSleep &dependency) {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( *dependency.m_pcvMutex );
    std::cv_status finishedWaiting = dependency.m_pConditionVariable ->wait_until( 
            lock
            , std::chrono::system_clock::now( ) + dependency.c_RecheckInterval_sec 
        );
    if ( std::cv_status::no_timeout == finishedWaiting )
        dependency.m_bBreak = true;
} } BreakableSleep;

struct InitialEmailCount { void operator()(dependencyEmailCount& dependency) {
    dependency.m_lastEmailCount = dependency.m_currentEmailCount;
} } InitialEmailCount;

struct EmailCounter { void operator()(dependencyEmailCount& dependency) {
    if ( dependency.m_currentEmailCount <= dependency.m_lastEmailCount )
        return;
    dependency.m_lastEmailCount = dependency.m_currentEmailCount;

    dependency.fnSetActiveTip( std::string{ }
            + "SmallImapsNotifier: last email\n"
            + "from: '" + dependency.lastFrom + "'\n"
            + "subject: '" + dependency.lastSubject + "'\n"
        );
} } EmailCounter;

struct InboxAvailable { void operator()(dependencyAvailable& dependency) {
    dependency.m_bAvailable = true;
} } InboxAvailable;

} // namespace Action

struct guardAvailable { 
    bool operator()(dependencyAvailable& dependency) const { 
        return !dependency.m_bAvailable;
    }
} guardAvailable;
struct guardBreak { 
    bool operator()(dependencyBreakableSleep &dependency) const { 
        return dependency.m_bBreak;
    }
} guardBreak;

struct ImapsSm {
  auto operator()() const noexcept {
    using namespace boost::sml;
    using namespace Action;
    return make_transition_table(
        // Using `state<>` to avoid print anonymous on sml logging in MSVC
        *state<struct idle> + event<CheckAccess> / Imap = "TryInbox"_s

        , "TryInbox"_s + event<Unavailable> [guardAvailable] = X
        , "TryInbox"_s + event<StartLoop> / InitialEmailCount = "Waiting"_s
        , "TryInbox"_s + on_entry<_> / InboxAvailable

        , "Waiting"_s + event<HasBreak> [guardBreak] = X
        , "Waiting"_s + event<RenewEmail> / Imap= "RenewedEmail"_s
        , "Waiting"_s + on_entry<_> / BreakableSleep

        , "RenewedEmail"_s + event<Unavailable> [guardAvailable] = X
        , "RenewedEmail"_s + event<ContinueLoop> = "Waiting"_s
        , "RenewedEmail"_s + on_entry<_> / ( InboxAvailable, EmailCounter )

        , *("exceptions handling"_s) + exception<_> / [](dependencyAvailable& dependency) { dependency.m_bAvailable = false; } = X
    );
  }
};
} // namespace StateMachine
```

**Thread.h**

```
#pragma once
class Thread {
    static constexpr std::chrono::seconds c_ReconnectTry_sec{ 60 };
    static constexpr std::chrono::seconds c_ConnectTimeout_sec{ 30 };
    static constexpr std::chrono::minutes c_RecheckInterval_minutes{ 5 };

    Credentials m_credentials;
    StateMachine::setActiveTip_t m_clbSetActiveTip;

    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::mutex m_cvMutex;
    std::atomic_bool m_bStop;
    std::thread m_thread;

    bool breakableWaitReconnect_() {
        if ( m_bStop )
            return false;
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( m_cvMutex );
        std::cv_status waiting = m_cv.wait_until( lock, 
            std::chrono::system_clock::now( ) + c_ReconnectTry_sec );
        return std::cv_status::timeout == waiting;
    }

    // thread
    void run() {
        namespace sml = boost::sml;
        using namespace StateMachine;
        do {
            dependencyImaps imaps = { m_credentials, c_ConnectTimeout_sec };
            dependencyEmailCount counter = { m_clbSetActiveTip };
            dependencyBreakableSleep sleep = { 
                    c_RecheckInterval_minutes
                    , &m_cv
                    , &m_cvMutex
                };
            sml::sm< ImapsSm > sm{ imaps, counter, sleep };
            sm.process_event( CheckAccess{ } );
            sm.process_event( Unavailable{ } );
            sm.process_event( StartLoop{ } );
            while ( !sm.is( sml::X ) ) {
                sm.process_event( HasBreak{ } );
                sm.process_event( RenewEmail{ } );
                sm.process_event( Unavailable{ } );
                sm.process_event( ContinueLoop{ } );
            }
        } while ( breakableWaitReconnect_( ) );
    }

 public:
    Thread(
        const Credentials &credentials
        , StateMachine::setActiveTip_t clbSetActiveTip
    )
        : m_credentials( credentials )
        , m_clbSetActiveTip( clbSetActiveTip )
        , m_bStop( false )
    {
        // will be init in last order
        m_thread = { &Thread::run, this };
    }

    void stop() {
        m_bStop = true;
        m_cv.notify_all( );
        m_thread.join( );
    }
};
```

demo **main.cpp**, with invalid login and password

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <mailio/imap.hpp>
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
struct Credentials {
    std::string host;
    uint16_t port;
    std::string login, password;
};
#include "Impl.h"
#include "Thread.h"
void main() {
    Credentials credentials = {
            "imap.gmail.com", 993, "%login%", "%password%"
        };
    auto imapsThread = std::make_unique< Thread >( 
            credentials
            , [](const std::string&str) {
                std::cout << str;
            }
        );
    getchar( );
}
```

How does all this correspond to the "canons" of state machines?
Not overkill?

Full code on GitHub [repo](https://github.com/Alex0vSky/SmallImapsNotifier)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unnecessary use of `std::unique_ptr`

You are using `std::unique_ptr` when there is no need for it. Both `pmailio` and `imapsThread` can just be stored by value:

```
struct Imap { void operator()(dependencyImaps &imaps, dependencyEmailCount& counter) {
    mailio::imaps pmailio(…);
    pmailio.authenticate(…);
    …
}
…
void main() {
    Credentials credentials = {…};
    Thread imapsThread(credentials, …);
    getchar();
}
```

## Lambdas are `struct`s

I see you write this pattern a few times:

```
struct Foo {
    void operator()(/* arguments */…) {
        /* body */
        …
    }
} Foo;
```

A lambda is just syntactic sugar for exactly that pattern! So you could also write:

```
auto Foo = [](/* arguments */…) {
    /* body */
    …
};
```

## Incorrect use of Hungarian notation

I see you are using some form of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). The problem with Hungarian notation is that nothing checks whether it is applied correctly. If you make mistakes, the whole benefit of Hungarian notation is kind of gone. Consider for example `c_connectTimeout_sec`. The `c_` prefix indicates that it's a `const` variable, however it is not. At the same time, `m_credentials` is `const` but that's not reflected in the prefix. You also use `cv` for condition variables, but then why is it `m_cvMutex`, when that variable is not a condition variable?

My advice is to stop using Hungarian notation, except for maybe using the prefix `m_` to indicate that something is a class member variable, but only because the latter is useful to avoid name conflicts with parameters and local variables.

## Don't mix atomics and mutexes

Make `m_bStop` a regular `bool`, and read and modify it only when holding a lock. Consider for example that `breakableWaitReconnect_()` has just checked `m_bStop`, and its value was `false`. The before it does anything else, `stop()` is called, which sets `m_bStop` to `true` (which does nothing)`, and which then calls` m_cv.notify_all()`(which also does nothing because no other thread is`wait()`ing yet`). Then `breakableWaitReconnect_()` continues, locks the mutex and callsl `m_cv.wait_until(…)`. Now you have to wait at least 60 seconds before that thread stops.

The correct way to handle this is to use a variant of `wait()` that uses a predicate, and to only modify `m_bStop` while holding the mutex:

```
bool breakableWaitReconnect_() {
    std::lock_guard lock(m_cvMutex);
    auto waiting = m_cv.wait_for(lock, c_ReconnectTry_sec, []{
        return m_bStop;
    });
    return std::cv_status::timeout == waiting;
}
…
void stop() {
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_cvMutex);
        m_bStop = true;
    }
    m_cv.notify_all( );
    m_thread.join( );
}
```

## Use `wait_for()` instead of `wait_until()`

If you only need to wait for a given period, then use [`wait_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for). Apart from not needing the manual calculation of the point in time to wait until, `wait_for()` also uses a [steady clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock), which is not affected by things like daylight savings time changes, or just someone adjusting their computer's clock. This avoids your code accidentally waiting for hours instead of seconds.

## About the use of state machines

There are several ways in which you could have approached this problem. The use of an explicit state machine is one way. The drawback is that you have to explicitly define all the states and their relationships with each other. Coroutines are another approach, which allows you to write code in a more natural way. Boost has coroutine libraries as well, and C++20 added native supported for [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), but you still need some external library at the moment to make effective use of them.

I don't think your use of Boost SML looks wrong, but I have never used it myself.

## Naming things

Some of your class names are very generic, and don't describe what they actually do. Consider `Thread` for example. That's way more than just being something like `std::thread`. You could name it `IMAPThread`. However, while it is *using* a thread, that might not be the most important thing to know about it. More important would be to know if this implements a client or a server. So perhaps `IMAPClient` is a better name? The same goes for `Credentials`: perhaps `IMAPClientCredentials` is more accurate.

Also consider using a `namespace` to group your classes together, and/or use the fact that you can nest class declarations. Since everything is related to IMAP, maybe use a hierarchy like:

```
namespace IMAP {

class Client {
public:
    class Credentials {
        …
    };
    …
};

}
```

Then your `main()` could look like:

```
void main() {
    using IMAP;
    Client::Credentials credentials = {…};
    Client client(credentials, …);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the description of the `wait_until()` feature -- i have not encountered this, and for 'race conditions' after mixing atomics and mutexes.
About _Hungarian notation_, it’s hard to get rid of this habit.
About **state machine**, it is very difficult to find real examples of application; basically everyone posts their own examples of implementations.
I prefer state machines to coroutines because of the _UML-like visualization_ capabilities.

Comment: Being able to easily visualize it is indeed one of the benefits of an explicit state machine. As for Hungarian notation being a habit: if there is no good basis for this habit, and you are not actually making good use of it, then consider that it's just [cargo cult progamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Also, it had a better purpose in the past when languages where much less strongly typed, but C++ is quite strict and thus the benefit of Hungarian notation, even if applied correctly, is very limited.

Comment: Confirm your statement about *notation*, entirely. The `c_connectTimeout_sec` variable was indeed a constant, but I shortened the code for the review by removing the bypass of the *sml* feature with initialization of constants. I wasnt sure where I would put the code from the `struct Imap` action in the future, so I left `std::unique_ptr` just in case, hurried - better to have an extra SmartPointer than to rewrite access operators. `IMAPThread/IMAPClientCredentials`: in the code there is only one thread and one credentials entity, so as not to overload the semantics, always omit clarifications

Comment: It will be much more fun for all of us if it soon becomes possible not only to visualize machines, but also to animate any transition options.